# Ionic Framework v1 post to server on a timer even in background

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, background, cordova-plugins

I am trying to set a timer within my app to go off at a certain time each day. Once that timer goes off, it needs to make a http.post to my nodejs server.

I already have the server setup and everything, this is just a feature in my app I would like to add so my users can setup automatic account backups (every day, hour, every other day, etc).

I am looking at this plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode But I don't think it is what I need.

I am using this plugin for local notifications: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/ and it works in the background perfectly.

Recap: I need to make some kind of timer that calls an event (in this case, a http post) and the timer will still work if the app is killed or in the background.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can follow this [link to build your own background service](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service.)

Its not easy as Native Android Services but you can give it a try :)

Comment: This doesn't look quite like what I need. It doesn't look like it'll work with ionic